# Clarification Needed on Javascript Coercion Concept

Tags: javascript, jquery

The Problem Here is When I try to add `"2"+"2"-"2"` in browser console, I get the result as `20`. `"2"+"2"` returns `"22"`(string), but `"2"+"2"-"2"` returns `20` (number). Can someone explain why is this happening? How Strings are Converted to resulting in number?

Comment: Because `"2" + "2" = "22", and `"22" - "2"` = 20.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In javascript :

`+` operator can append string or perform numeric operation

but - * / can be perform only on numeric values only

```js
var a = "2";
var b = "2";
var c = "2";

var temp1 = a+b;
console.log("After + --> ",typeof(temp1) , temp1 );

var temp2 = temp1-c;
console.log("After - --> ",typeof(temp2) , temp2 );

var temp3 = temp1*c;
console.log("After * --> ",typeof(temp3) , temp3 );

var temp4 = temp1/c;
console.log("After / --> ",typeof(temp4) , temp4 );
```

Here is the great article regarding this : **[Read More (+)](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascriptss-addition-operator-demystified/)** / **[Read More (-)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/subtraction-operator-decrement-javascript)**

> operand + operand = result
>
> 1. If at least one operand is an object, it is converted to a primitive value (string, number or boolean);
> 2. After conversion, if at least one operand is string type, the second operand is converted to string and the concatenation is
>      executed;
> 3. In other case both operands are converted to numbers and arithmetic addition is executed.
>
> If both operands are primitive types, then operator checks if at least
>   one is string and executes the concatenation. In other case it just
>   transforms everything to numbers and sum.

For all other Operators : **[Do Read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators)**

Comment: can you explain in depth?

Comment: @ChandraShekhar , Okay I have also added the snippets , you can check that , I think it will clear the doubts

Comment: if possible send me article about subtraction operator.

Comment: @ChandraShekhar , Yeah Sure give me a min

Comment: @ChandraShekhar , please check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators

Comment: gone through the MDN Docs, Could not find in depth on subtraction operator, any way thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @ChandraShekhar , https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/subtraction-operator-decrement-javascript